# how to use the rayshader packge for 3D surface from x, y, z

Tags: r, 3d, surface, rayshader

imagine I have a 3 columns matrix
x, y, z where z is a height/intensity of x and y.

```
x = runif(1000)
y = runif(1000)
z = rnorm(1000)
```

How to use the rayshader packge for 3D surface from x, y, z?

although the rgl could do it, i think is it possible to directly use the rayshader for 3D surface from x, y, z?

Thanks
hees

Answer (score 0):

You could use `akima::interp` to approximate the surface with a matrix of values, and maybe `rayshader::ray_shade` can handle that.  Code would be

```
m <- akima::interp(x, y, z, nx = 200, ny = 200)
s <- rayshader::ray_shade(m$z)
```

This gives a matrix of shade values; it doesn't draw anything.  To draw something, you'll need to turn those values into colours, and display them. For example,

```
plot(as.raster(s))
```

which gives this plot:

[image]